# Is there a way to iterate through a timer in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, iteration

I'm trying to create a Pomodoro timer using Hooks and I have set up the basic functionality using useState and useEffect. I have a 25-minute timer that counts down and every time it gets to 0, it starts a break timer of 5 minutes. What I'm trying to figure out now is how to create an iteration that says "every 4 times the timer hits 0, change the break time from 5 minutes to 15 minutes and then, go back to 5 minutes." I thought of creating sessions that way it will say 4th session and then it will go back to 1. but I'm really not sure what to do here.

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Pomodoro() {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(25);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      clearInterval(interval);

      if (seconds === 0 && minutes !== 0) {
        setSeconds(59);
        setMinutes(minutes -1);
      } else if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        let minutes = displayMessage ? 24 : 4;
        let seconds = 59;

        setSeconds(seconds);
        setMinutes(minutes);
        setDisplayMessage(!displayMessage);
      } else {
        setSeconds(seconds -1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [seconds]);

  const timerMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
  const timerSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
  return (
    <div className="pomodoro">
        <div>Session:{session} </div>
      <div className="message">
        {displayMessage && <div>Break time! New Session starts in:</div>}
      </div>
      <div className="timer">
        {timerMinutes}:{timerSeconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pomodoro;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using a counter to keep track of the completed sessions seems to make sense. If you want to use a different amount of break time for every fourth iteration, you could use the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator as below:

`let breakTime = (session % 4) === 0 ? 14 : 0;`

Then, you just need to make sure you are incrementing your `session` variable by one each time you complete a session. This also means you only want to increase it when you are not "on break" so you must make sure to guard against that.

Updating the answer with the full code that I tested to be working. Note the following changes I made:

- I am only keeping track of the timer in seconds - this reduces the complexity inside `useEffect` and you can convert from seconds to other formats (try using the remainder operator again)
- Moved the period lengths to constants
- Renamed the variable `displayMessage` to `isOnBreak` for clarity

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Define the period lengths (in seconds)
const workTime = 2;
const shortBreakTime = 4;
const longBreakTime = 6;

function Pomodoro() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(workTime);
  // Renamed this variable for clarity to indicate it is a boolean
  const [isOnBreak, setIsOnBreak] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      clearInterval(interval);

      if (seconds === 0) {
        let breakTime = (session % 4 === 0) ? longBreakTime : shortBreakTime;
        let seconds = !isOnBreak ? breakTime : workTime;
        // A session is complete when work and break is done, 
        // so only increment when finishing a break
        if (isOnBreak) setSession(session+1);
        setSeconds(seconds);
        setIsOnBreak(!isOnBreak);
      } else {
        setSeconds(seconds -1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [seconds]);

  // Here you could convert from seconds to minutes and seconds or whatever time format you prefer
  const timerSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
  return (
    <div className="pomodoro">
        <div>Session:{session} </div>
      <div className="message">
        {isOnBreak && <div>Break time! New Session starts in:</div>}
      </div>
      <div className="timer">
        {timerSeconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: now I'm having issues like you said for me to safe guard, I'm trying to use instead of (displayMessage) i'm trying to say
if (minutes === 24 && seconds === 59) setSession (prev => prev +1) 
however, it's still thinking that a break is a session. I'm stuck, any help? lol

Comment: Without seeing the code, I cannot say for sure, but I updated the answer with a more complete solution which I was able to test to be working as you describe.